# Spotfire calculated columns OVER multiple qualifiers selected on the fly

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

Is it possible to create a calculated column in Spotfire OVER whatever is selected on a graph (x.axis?) I know I can do this by creating a graph/visualization and then creating a custom expression, but I'd like to use that expression multiple times and have the values change according to what I am filtering by, and not have to recreate this on multiple graphs, just be able to call the value.

I.e., I'd like to perform this calculation, OVER multiple qualifiers / combination of qualifiers what I would select on the fly.

```
Sum([Var1]) / 2 / Sum([Var2])

OVER

Qualifier 1, Qualifier 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do. could you provide some sample data or a more detailed example of what this expression might look like?

Comment: You'll likely need a document property based off columns, paired with  `Intersect()` but as @niko stated sample data and expected out put would help. -Roll Tide